# How do I write to the file I selected using filedialog.asksaveasfile?

Tags: python, tkinter, savefiledialog

I am trying to write to a file that I just created using the filedialog.asksaveasfile. I set the mode to 'w'. Do I have to open the file again or something?

```
f = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".csv")

keyList = []

for n in aDict.keys():
    keyList.append(n)

keyList = sorted(keyList, key=operator.itemgetter(0,1))
csvWriter = csv.writer(f)

for key in keyList:
    sal1 = aDict[(key[0],key[1])][0]
    sal2 = aDict[(key[0],key[1])][1]
    csvWriter.writerow(key[0], key[1], sal1, sal2)

f.close()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply use the `write` function of the reference (of type `_io.TextIOWrapper`) returned by the `asksaveasfile` function.

For example

```
from tkinter import filedialog, Tk

root = Tk().withdraw()

file = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".csv")

if file:
    file.write("Hello World")
    file.close()
```

Note that the object returned by the `asksaveasfile` function is of the same *type* or *class* of the object returned by the built-in `open` function. Note also that the same function returns `None`, if `Cancel` is pressed when the dialog pops up.